# Add 360 photo to jekyll post or background

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, photo

I'd like to add 360 photos in posts in a jekyll web page. I already know that there are some services where I can store those and then add the photo to the post with the `iframe` structure.

What I want is to have the photos stored in the server folders (*images*) and add the photo as a frame or as a background using [panolens.js](https://pchen66.github.io/Panolens/)

[For example in this case they do this editing the index.html](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuOmD7cnygk). What I'd like is to get this via jekyll post markdown or in other way. For example something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to define a liquid array of photos URLs right in the post; careful to indent the array elements and put a space after the - sign

```
---
layout: post
title: Photos
gallery:     
    - https://path/to/photos/photo1.jpg
    - https://path/to/photos/photo2.jpg
    - https://path/to/photos/photo3.jpg
---
```

and then in the post.html layout I just display them with my preferred style, the minimal is this but of course, you can use your preferred gallery slideshow:

```
{% for image in page.gallery %}
    <img src="{{ image }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This will show the photos in the actual format (2:1) but not in 3D view mode I think...

Comment: No you'd have to adapt the code to your own purpose